# How to restrict methods not GET or POST either

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a project mounted on AWS and I need the root URL of the web application to return a status code of 405 for methods other than POST or GET. I've tried changing the middleware of each lambda project to reject those connections. But the root URL still accepts them. I have touched the API gateway, I do not know if well, to let pass the GET and POST methods and the ANY return a 405, but it does not seem to work either. Can you give me a hand?

**API GATEWAY**

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot how have you setup resources (routes) and methods in API Gateway?

Comment: @AnkushJain Thanks for your response. I added the screenshot, I hope it is you are looking for.

Comment: @AnkushJain I tried that before and it is not working. I tried again calling with a OPTIONS method and I still receive a 200 status code from POSTMAN

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it step by step.

1. Created any **ANY** method with **Mock integration**.

   [image]
2. In **Method Response**, added 405 status code as well along with 200.

   [image]
3. Finally, updated **Integration Response** to return 405 status code, as shown below.

   [image]
4. Tested from an online tool.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Yep, I tried a version of your solution before and nothing. I re tried your solution, exactly the same, and it is still not working. Strange... What are we missing?

Comment: Did you deploy the API after making changes?

Comment: Yes, twice just in case

Comment: Don't know, for me it worked as you can see the screenshot in step 4. May be you missed something in step 2 or 3.

Comment: which url are you blocking? it must be the root one

Comment: Yes…root one for all other method types except POST.

Comment: I mean, I think the error could be here, the one where was published the web. Not the one used by amazon. For example, something like: https:/www.google.com

Comment: I rate your answer btw. Many Thanks